# Which type of quotes we should use in css background url ("....")? Single, double or no quote needed?

Tags: grammar, css

this

```
background:url(http://url);
```

this

```
background:url("http://url");
```

or this

```
background:url('http://url');
```

Comment: I know it's valid to not use quotes, but it doesn't feel right to me!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The URL bits of all three of your examples are valid CSS, according to the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri).

Note that the spec identifies some characters in a URL which will need to be escaped with a backslash if present `in an unquoted URI, such as parentheses, commas, white space characters, single quotes (') and double quotes (").` For this reason, you might find it better to use single or double quotes around your URLs.

Note that you need to write your full CSS property in the format:

```
background: url( http://example.com );
```

Comment: u mean if url has special character then single or double quote should be used.

Comment: no - you can include a url with special characters without quotes provided that you escape the quotes with a backslash (like such: http://example.com/lo\\(url\\)wi) - my point was that you'll find it easier to quote all of your urls ("http://example.com/lo(url)wi") rather than escape the ones which are troublesome

Comment: @dexter - that same i was saying it's good to use quote always.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any are right. It should be one of these:

```
background: url(http://url)

background: url("http://url")

background: url('http://url')
```

Note the colon, instead of curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

It is your choice, according to W3:

> The format of a URI value is 'url('
>   followed by optional white space
>   followed by an optional single quote
>   (') or double quote (") character
>   followed by the URI itself, followed
>   by an optional single quote (') or
>   double quote (") character followed by
>   optional white space followed by ')'.
>   The two quote characters must be the
>   same.

Answer (score 1):

I use the one without quotes. I remember reading something by Zeldman that said it was the least likely to cause problems with legacy browsers. I believe the browser he mentioned was ancient, like Netscape 2 or something. Nowadays, it wouldn't matter which style you use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems any of the quoted or non quoted are acceptable (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/)

BUT these below are only used IF you are referencing resource outside of your domain.

```
background: url(http://url)
background: url("http://url")
background: url('http://url')
```

IF you are on the same domain: (The "HTTP://" is not required, as previously mentioned)

```
background: url(/path/to/file)
background: url("/path/to/file")
background: url('/path/to/file')
```