# css margin/border/padding have no effect whatsoever on LI items

Tags: html, css

In the following very simple html, I've been unable to get the margin/border/padding of my unordered list to be anything other than the default.  I've tried "5em", "50em", "100px"...with no effect whatsoever.

Chrome's "developer tools" window shows my css, but in a cross-out font.  I know that means my css has been overridden by something.  But by what?  What could possibly be higher-priority than the plain instructions in this file itself?

And I know I shouldn't need to fiddle with margin, border and padding all together, to get what I want (which is nothing more than extra-wide left indentation) but after *margin: "0 0 0 5em"* failed, I tried to see if *anything* worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style>
    ul li {
      margin: "5em 5em 5em 5em";
      border: "5em 5em 5em 5em";
      padding: "5em 5em 5em 5em";
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li> foo </li>
    <ul>
      <li> a </li>
      <li> b </li>
      <li> c </li>
    </ul>
    <li> bar </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are the values wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Also `border: 5em 5em 5em 5em;` isn't a valid CSS rule. When chrome shows the rule crossed out with the yellow "warning" icon next to it, it means that it's an invalid rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to use quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899478/where-to-use-quotes)

Comment: It looks like you are new to CSS. Refer the following css properties. You'll be able to get your doubts cleared - [Margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp), [Padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp), [Border](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 1):

None of your values used in the CSS are valid, and so they're crossed out because the browser doesn't understand them.

See below, I've adjusted the values. First off, none of them can be quoted; only certain values are quoted, like when there's a space in a single value.

For `padding` and `margin`, only a single value is needed if all 4 values are the same, otherwise:

- Two values affect `vertical` then `horizontal` (respectively)
- Three values affect `top`, `horizontal`, then `bottom`
- Four values affect `top`, `right`, `bottom`, then `left`

For Border however, it defines all 4 borders with 3 values:
 - Width (1em, 5px, etc) that defines the width of the line
 - Linetype (solid, dashed, etc)
 - Colour (`#FFF`,`rgba(255,200,0,1)`)

To affect individual borders, you need to use `border-top`, `border-right`, border-bottom`,`border-left`.

**EDIT:** I would suggest checking out some documentation. Personally I prefer the MDN (Mozilla Developer Network):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style>
    ul li {
      margin: 1em;
      border: 1em solid #000;
      padding: 1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li> foo </li>
    <ul>
      <li> a </li>
      <li> b </li>
      <li> c </li>
    </ul>
    <li> bar </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from your CSS properties:

```
ul li {
    margin: 5em;
    border: 5em solid #FF0000
    padding: 5em;
}
```

Note that if you are going to use the same value 4 times, you can only write it once as a short-cut. And notice how the border values are set.