# For CSS font-family property, are 'Helvetica Neue' vs "Helvetica Neue" and 'Roboto' vs Roboto the same?

Tags: css

I found people wrote CSS like

```
h1 {font-family: "Helvetica Neue"}
h1 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'}
h1 {font-family: 'Roboto'}
h1 {font-family: Roboto}
```

I saw most of the people use `'` more and `'Roboto'` more than `Roboto`.

Is there even any tiny difference?

BTW, I asked this question because I saw this on Google Fonts:

[image]

If there's no difference, why does Google bother adding a `'` in it?

Comment: I'd say the difference would come if any of `'` or `"` characters were part of the font name

Comment: This could be of an interesting read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688298/1248133 Similar to what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You can always put a specific font family name in quotes, double or single, so Roboto, "Roboto", and 'Roboto' are equivalent. Only the CSS-defined generic font family names like sans-serif must be written without quotes.

Contrary to popular belief, a font name consisting of space-separated names such as Helvetica Neue need not be quoted. However, the spec recommends “to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters other than hyphens”