# Slash in string disappears in HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

```
    table += "<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url('images/video_icons/" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + "');'></img>"
```

This is the following code i have (where videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] is simply just "moo.png" or some other picture)

For whatever reason, when i view the html it shows the background url as `images video_icons moo.png` instead of having the slashes.

I think it has to do with "style" since when i change this to:

```
    table += "<img class='thumb' src='images/video_icons/" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + "'></img>"
```

An image displays (although it does no longer what i want it to do, the slash signs are there)

Any idea what to do? Thanks!

---

**Edit:**
I have the following CSS for the class `thumb`:

```
.thumb { display: inline-block; 
         width: 200px; 
         height: 100px;  
         margin: 5px;  
         background-position: center center;  
         background-size: cover;  
}
```

and a fiddle (without the javascript) here: http://jsfiddle.net/lucyguo/5wxBP

Comment: Switch your single quotes to double and double to single...I once had a problem similar to yours and that fixed it. I think there is ambiguity with double vs single in terms of markup

Answer (score 3):

You have you're quotes confused.  The specific area is at`style='background-image: url('images/video_icons/" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + "');'`.  You have single quotes within an attribute who's value is already in single quotes.  You can either escape them or just remove them since you don't need them for the url.

Change to the following:

```
 "<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url('images/video_icons/" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + "');'></img>"
```

To:

```
 "<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url(images/video_icons/" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + ");'></img>"
```

Answer (score 0):

The image element has 2 required attributes, 'src' and 'alt'.
Where 'alt' is an alternative text being displayed when the image can't be found, and 'src' is the url to the image.
You are not using any of these attributes.
Because i don't see anything else in your style attribute you should just use the 'src' attribute like you did in your second code example.

[Img element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Comment: Not sure whether to upvote: [alt isn't required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img), but the problem is the src attribute, as you identified.

Comment: .thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
is the style attribute; it works in fiddle as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucyguo/5wxBP/

Answer (score 0):

***Escaping*** is the (biggest) problem (as Daniel Gimenez already identified while I was still typing this answer), but do read the edit below!

Your first string would render the following (obviously) invalid HTML (note the nested `'` characters, the closing tag and the lack of a `src` attribute):

```
<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url('images/video_icons/moo.png');'></img>
```

I'll try to explain *the escaping* in simple steps (so future readers can do this on their own).

But first, an image is a `void` element, meaning it has *no* closing-tag.
So imagine you want this as your resulting html:

```
<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url("images/video_icons/moo.png");'>
```

then in javascript you'd choose the `"` character to wrap your string; that way there are only 2 (instead of 4) characters to escape.

Note *that whilst you can generally leave out the [quotes in the css url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034587/588079), one must know the exceptions when this doesn't work, so it is safest to use the quotes, then you don't need to remember anything* (making it an error-proof and consistent coding style).

Now let's wrap and escape that string (for javascript):

```
"<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url(\"images/video_icons/moo.png\");'>"
```

Finally, you want javascript to provide the variable 'moo.png' string.
For clarity, I'll first replace it with a `?`.

```
"<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url(\"images/video_icons/" + ? + "\");'>"
```

Now let's replace that `?` with your `videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"]`  (It does not matter in this case if you used `'` or `"` to call your `Thumbnail Title` property):

```
"<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url(\"images/video_icons/" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + "\");'>"
```

That is it! Ok, you'd need to append that string to your `table` var: `table += ? ;` :

```
table += "<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url(\"images/video_icons/" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + "\");'>";
```

Hope this helps in the future!

---

**EDIT:**

**Stefan Koenen has a good point about the image's missing `src` attribute.**
In [HTML4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) the `src` (and `alt`) are `required`. In the [HTML5 proposal](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element), only the `src` is mandatory (and must be valid) whilst the `alt` attribute is debatable.
Apart from these rues, just for the sake of cross-browser-compatibility, authors have opted for 1 of the following 2 common solutions:

1. Use a `div`
   (instead of an image, seems most appropriate solution in this case)
2. Set the `src` attribute of the image to a transparent gif of 1*1px.
   (Also 'costs' extra image to be loaded)

[Here is an excellent rule of thumb for making such (design-)decisions about the usage of images.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336431/588079)

Answer (score 0):

Due to HTML rendering slashes getting disappeared. just add double slashes instead of single

```
table += "<img class='thumb' style='background-image: url('images//video_icons//" + videos[i]["Thumbnail Title"] + "');'></img>"
```